# Trouble Communicating with SIM7600X 4G HAT via Minicom on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, qualcomm, sim7600

I'm having trouble getting my Raspberry Pi to communicate with a SIM7600X 4G HAT using Minicom. I can't seem to input any AT commands into Minicom or any other terminal emulator.

Here's a summary of the situation, hardware setup, and the steps I've taken so far:

### Hardware Setup:

- Raspberry Pi model: 4B
- SIM7600X 4G HAT seated on the GPIO pins
- Using the USB port on the HAT (not the UART bridge)
- Power supply: 6.5A power charger

### Initial Problem:

- Minicom does not accept any keyboard input when opened.
- Tried connecting with both symlink /dev/sim7600x_usb and direct /dev/ttyUSB* paths.

### Steps Taken:

Checked Hardware Connections:

- Ensured the HAT is properly seated and USB cable is secure.
- Tried different USB cables and ports.

### Confirmed Power Requirements:

- Verified that the power supply is adequate (2.5A or greater).

### Reviewed Jumper and Switch Settings:

- Checked the DIP switch and jumper settings based on the Waveshare guide showing 3v3 and PWR as jumper shorted
- UART Jumper set to short A&B on both left and right pins

### LED Status Jumper and Switch Settings:

- Solid Red PWR
- Flashing Red NET

### Ensured Correct Drivers:

- Confirmed that usbserial and option drivers are loaded.

### Disabled Serial Console Over GPIO:

- Used raspi-config to disable serial console and enable serial hardware.

### Verified Modem Detection:

- The dmesg command shows the modem cycling through ttyUSB devices (indicating possible power issues or mode switching).

### Attempted Direct Connection without Symlink:

- Tried accessing the modem using /dev/ttyUSBx directly in Minicom.

### Ran Minicom with Superuser Permissions:

- Used sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSBx.

### Tested Minicom Without Configuration File:

- Executed sudo minicom --noinit -D /dev/ttyUSBx.

### Checked for Conflicting Processes:

- Ensured no other process is using the modem with lsof | grep ttyUSBx.

### Rebooted Raspberry Pi:

- After making configuration changes, rebooted to ensure changes took effect.

### Current State:

- /dev/sim7600x_usb points to bus/usb/001/088 instead of a /dev/ttyUSB* device.
- DIP switches on the HAT are set according to the manual, but I can't confirm this is correct.
- When connected via USB, dmesg shows the device repeatedly connecting and disconnecting from ttyUSB ports.
- I'm unsure if this issue is caused by power instability, incorrect mode settings on the HAT, or a problem with the drivers or Raspberry Pi configuration.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!